# Error "The method * is not applicable for the arguments" in Eclipse Java editor but not Problems view

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a class called `ParentClass` and two child classes, let's call them `Child1` and `Child2` which extends from `ParentClass`.

And I have a method which recieves the `ParentClass` as parameter, like this:

```
private void myMethod(ParentClass myObject) {
    // Do something...
}
```

I should be able to call the method and pass an instance of any of the two child classes (because they extend from `ParentClass`), like this

```
Child1 child1 = new Child1();
Child2 child2 = new Child2();

myMethod(child1); // Error is displayed on this line
myMethod(child2); // Error is displayed on this line
```

But the Eclipse Java editor is complaining with this error:

```
The method myMethod(ParentClass) in the type Test is not applicable for the arguments (Child1)
```

The strange this is that the error is displayed only in the Java Editor, but on the `Problems` or `Markers` view, also not on the `Project Explorer` view, the code complies and run successfully so I'm not sure why the error is displayed in the editor.

**------EDIT------**

Tried cleaning the projects, restarting Eclipse with the `-clean` option, exporting and importing the project in a new workspace.

Comment: Build clean and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: I tried that, also restarting Eclipse didn't work, please see my edit

Comment: Are you sure your `Child1` and `Child2` extend `ParentClass`? Like, no typos?

Comment: Is Eclipse doing the compiling, or is another tool like Ant or Maven orchestrating it?

Comment: I'm sure `Child1` and `Child2` extends from `ParentClass` and yes, Eclipse is handling the compiling.

Answer (score 1):

You can **delete the errors in the problems view.** After you do that, do a clean build. If the problem does not come back, you have probably fixed it. You might try to do "validation", but that is generally for other types of problems. You also might try `Run->Maven clean verify` if it is a maven project. That will compile it "from the command line" and insure eclipse is not magically resolving dependencies for you. Basically, however, I've seen problems stay in the problems windows after they were fixed. I rarely use the windows output for normal work, generally only when there is a red `X` somewhere in the project that I don't understand.

Comment: But I have no problems in the `Problems` or the `Makrers` views, only the Java Editor displays the error, but I can't see the error anywhere else

Answer (score 0):

Have you compiled the code on the command line?